# Comodo SSL not working Internally

Tags: ssl, iis

So I've set up a Comodo SSL certificate which is working fine:-

https://infinityfinance.net/

This was configured on the Windows 10 machine using IIS. This works perfect and I can see it's secure but it doesn't seem to work on the local network for some reason.

I just get a certificate warning and can't access the web site, this is when I am trying to access the web site via https://infinityfinance.net/ and not localhost, please advise.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: *"I just get a certificate warning..."* - please provide the details of this warning.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - I've added this

Comment: I don't think I really understand what you are doing. You are claiming that you've setup this certificate locally on some Win10 machine - although this is a public reachable site. So do you have problems accessing the public reachable site or the internal site setup with the same name? And how did you verify that the internal site was setup properly and did not inadvertently checked the public site? And how do you make sure that your test reach the internal site and not the public site with the same name?

Comment: Just remember that Firefox uses its own certificate store.  I would create a new Firefox user profile to confirm this isn't the case of an improper profile configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate you have in the post doesn't seem to be the one I see
coming from the website.

The website certificate begins on 24 September 2018 and expires on 25 September 2019,
so is entirely valid.
The certificate displayed above has expired on 22 May 2017, so is no longer valid.

Check you are using the same certificate on the website and in your local
website.